# Update the selected view in list view webpart using C#

Tags: development, 2016, ssom

Please help me to reflect the view changes to the web part pages programmatically using C#

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The following SSOM code for your reference.

```
var siteUrl = "http://sp2013/sites/team";
var pageUrl = siteUrl + "/SitePages/TestChangeView.aspx";
var listName = "TestCustomList";
var viewName = "TestView";
var webpartTitle = "TestCustomList";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFile file = web.GetFile(pageUrl);
        SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

        SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
        SPView view = list.Views[viewName];

        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in mgr.WebParts)
        {
            if (wp.Title == webpartTitle)
            {
                XsltListViewWebPart xsltwp = wp as XsltListViewWebPart;
                PropertyInfo pi = xsltwp.GetType().GetProperty("ContextView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                SPView wpView = (SPView)(pi.GetValue(xsltwp, null));
                wpView.SetViewXml(view.GetViewXml());
                wpView.Update();
                mgr.SaveChanges(xsltwp);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```